# Emmet abbreviation syntax multiplication now working

Tags: html, emmet

In VSCODE emmet element multiplication is not working....

For Example-

```
h1*3
```

Should Show results like below

```
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1></h1>
```

But in my case it's not working.....other then this other emmet is working fine

Answer (score 1):

the plugin for html has been deprecated,

you can install extension "Emmet Live",

you can download from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ysemeniuk.emmet-live) or open your visual studio code and install it from extension marketplace

after you install it press F1 on VSC and type Emmet live and enter your command,
in your case the command is h1*3 and done.